# How much secure is to mount and immediately read and external device

Tags: mount, clamav, thunar-custom-actions

I know that, up today, there are not known viruses to Linux, but...

How much secure is to mount and immediately read the content of an external unit (USB pendrive or whatever).

I'm talking about the options of the standard Thunar file manager.

Is there some way to use ClamAV antivirus to check, automatically, that external units?

Comment: A device from trusted source can be read immediately. IIRC USBs should be mounted without executable privillege enabled ( so scripts on them should not run ). Questionable devices could potentially attempt exploiting kernel vulnerabilities or otherwise masquerade as harmless block storage. There is also something known as USB killer, which physically damages USB ports, and masqueraded as USB drive physically.  Automatic ClamAV is possible via udev rules - these are commonly used to edit device or run script upon plugging in. Of course, there is a lot more detail to it that can fit in a comment

Comment: The short answer is that it is inherently insecure to attach anything that is from questionable sources, regardless if it is Linux or Windows

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! But... Where can I find that `udev rules` to automatize ClamAV?

Comment: There is an  example of running scripts for USB via udev rules https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28548/85039  I would love to write an answer but lately havent had much time to do so.  If you cannot get it working ping me over the weekend and I will try my best to put something together ( unless someone else does it before that )

Comment: But any "infected" files found by ClamAV are "infected" with Windows malware, which doesn't run on Linux, anyway. Mounting with `nodev,noexec,nosuid,owner,user` (and, for FAT, `uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)`) should be safe. But beware "BadUSB" which looks like a USB key, but tells the computer "I'm a USB keyboard!Type this:"

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy!!! But... I'm not a programmer and I will take some time to learn how to do that. I think there should be some GUI app where we can program all the `clamav` automatic jobs (not the today `clamtk` which is useful ONLY when we manually scan files).